# How to rotate a single layer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a custom raster layer and I want to be able to rotate it. I know that it is possible to rotate the whole map, like:

```
...
var view = new ol.View({
    ...
    rotation: Math.PI / 6,
    ...
}); 
...
```

And in this case the whole map is rotated. What I want is just to rotate a single layer.

Comment: Care to elaborate why? It seems such an odd request, just making sure it could not be handled differently (e.g. coordinate transformation seems more likely).

Comment: I have large big rasters and I have vector graphics. I've made some UI, that now enables to move and scale these rasters to accomodate them to vector layer. The way I do it is through JavaScript proj4j library. The only requirement, that I cannot meet is to rotate these rasters